# R's grepl is unable to find strings

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row, grepl

I am trying to delete all the rows in a Dataframe with the string "$null$". I was trying to use the following code to achieve that for a column called "resale". Can someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong here.

```
cars3 <- cars_2[!grepl("$null$", cars_2$resale),]
```

Answer (score 3):

`$` is a regex metacharacter, indicating the string-last position. If you refer to it literally, you need to escape it:

```
 cars3 <- cars_2[!grepl("\\$null\\$", cars_2$resale),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `fixed = TRUE`

```
cars3 <- cars_2[grep("$null$", car2_2$resale, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE),]
```